# Question about normalization factors in the direct integral of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

So the original question I wanted to ask was this one:

I'm currently a bit puzzled about the normalization for the Gelfand transform $U$:
So if we have a periodic Schrödinger operator $H$, then we can decompose it into a direct integral over the (what the physicists call) Brioullin zone $B$ (that is roughly the idea):
$$UHU^{-1} = \int_{B}^{\oplus} H(k) dk$$
Now, I sometimes see references where a normalization appears in the measure of the direct-integral, although I don't understand why it is necessary!
As an example, let me attach the following 
[theorem from Reed Simon Analysis of Operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm86u.jpg)

I think I understand the proof, but I don't see any explanation why there is a normalization by $(2\pi)$ (of the direct integral's measure) in the the theorem. In my opinion this would mean that $(UHU^{-1}f)(\theta,x) = \frac{(Vf)(\theta,x)}{2\pi} = \frac{(Vf)(x)}{2\pi} $ which is obviously not what they calculated (in their calculation no $2\pi$ appears), but this the definition of $(\int_{[0,2\pi)}^{\oplus} \frac{V(\theta)}{2\pi} d\theta f)(\theta, x)$ as far as I know. So something about this $2 \pi$ is weird here. Why is it there in the theorem although it does not show up in the proof?
If anything is unclear, please let me know.
**Now**, I noticed that somehow the definition of the direct integral of operators does not depend very much on the definition of the concrete measure, i.e.

if $d\lambda$ is one measure and the other one is equivalent to $d\lambda$, let us say $d\mu = 5d\lambda$ then the direct integrals

$$\int_{M}^{\oplus} H(k) d \lambda(k) = \int_{M}^{\oplus} H(k) d \mu(k)$$ are exactly the same. Is this really true or am I missing something? (This would of course also answer the previous question, if you consider the factor $\frac{1}{(2\pi)}$ as part of the measure. But somehow this looks extremely weird to me.

Comment: A physics insight for a physics inspired question: The integral of H over k has units of [H] times units of [k], while the left hand side has units of [H], so there must be an implicit normalization with units 1/[k] on the r.h.s. For the $\theta$ integral, in particular, $\theta$ has units of radians, so there must be a normalization constant with inverse radian units, and the inverse of $2 \pi$ radians is the obvious normalization for an integral from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Comment: Please don't make all these minor edits just to bump your question

Comment: Use of the term "crackpot" in this context does not seem to be constructive.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I doubt the direct integral will sue me

Comment: I don't see how it's the right word, so I am replacing it with something that seems more informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the point is that a "direct integral of operators" just means that you have a bounded measurable family of operators on the fibers of a bundle of Hilbert spaces, and you apply them all at once to get a single operator on the space of $L^2$ sections of the bundle. Of course the space of $L^2$ sections of the bundle depends on the choice of measure on the base space.

Once a measure is used to define the space of $L^2$ sections it wouldn't even make sense to talk about a direct integral of operators with respect to some other measure acting on that space. Maybe that is the confusion?

Comment: in some sense yes. Because what I tried to point out what confused me is: If you start initially with a different measure that is let's say $5-$ times the initial one, then you get the same object, but you can write down equalities that look very weird.

Comment: Yes, well, "the same object" in the sense that $L^2[0,1]$ is "the same" as $L^2[0,5]$ --- there's a natural isomorphism, anyway.